# How does the MemoryMappedViewAccessor.ReadArray<T> method work internally

Tags: c#, arrays, memory-mapped-files

I have always been in the BinaryReader or Stream to have a method to read array in quick way. Since MS has introduced the MemoryMappedFiles there has been one class MemoryMappedViewAccessor that has a method which is called ReadArray to read arrays.

Has someone an idea how this method works. Currently it's horrible to read arrays from a binary stream. You first have to read the stream as bytes and them copy the byte stream into the target array format. It would be nice to have it in one step.

I tried to enable to .NET-Framework source-stepping in VS2010 but it doesn't work.

Currently I read my data for several primitive array datatypes, like this:

```
public static float[] ReadSingles(this Stream stream_in, int count)
    {
        FileStream fileStream = stream_in as FileStream;

        float[] Data = new float[count];

        if (count == 0) return Data;

            fixed (float* dataptr = &Data[0])
            {
                if ((fileStream == null) || (StreamExt.Mode == StreamExtMode.Conventional))
                {
                    byte[] bts = ReadBytes(stream_in, count * sizeof(float));// stream_in.ReadBytes(count * sizeof(float));
                    Marshal.Copy(bts, 0, new IntPtr(dataptr), bts.Length);
            }
        }

        return Data;
    }
```

Is there a good answer to this.

Thanks
Martin

Comment: Have you ever heard of Reflector or ILSpy?

Comment: "Currently it's horrible to read arrays from a binary stream. You first have to read the stream as bytes and them copy the byte stream into the target array format." I'm very unclear what you mean here - I do ***lots*** of `Stream` work and it is not a problem. If this is the problem you are trying to solve (with memory-mapped files just being a tool), please clarify what you mean here, as I might be able to help.

Comment: Hi marc, the memorymappedfile mentioned here was just an example to illustrate that there is a method to read arrays. May problem is that I'm having data most of the which is approx.5-20GB. During processing the data (I have to go through all the data) I created a secondary amount of data which sometimes exceeds 100GB. This should all be done in a quick way. I will try to add an example of how I currently read the data.

Comment: I added a code example of how I read the arrays now.

Comment: jcolebrand. I have never tried, but it's a good time to start. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @msedi - updated answer re your edit

Answer (score 2):

It boils down to an `extern` method, so in short: *we can't see directly*. It isn't done in managed code, but by the CLI host:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
private static extern unsafe void PtrToStructureNative(
         byte* ptr, TypedReference structure, uint sizeofT);
```

Re your existing code; IMO, the issue here is your choice to allocate `count * sizeof(float)` If your intention is to avoid the additional `byte[]` overhead, I would create a *smaller* buffer (say, `Max(count, 1000) * sizeof(float)`) and use a loop, filling in `Data` progressively.

Also, if you don't need all the floats at once, consider an iterator block instead, which will *slash* the memory overheads here (but will mean you only have access to the items as a sequence, not random access).

Comment: Hi Marc, you are right. This is what I'm currently doing. I run through the data which is seperated in approx. 10000 blocks each having a datasize of say 100000bytes. Sometimes I can do it sequentially, sometimes random access. Summing up all these steps causes a lot of overhead due to the cast from byte to the target type. Therefore I'd like to get rid of the cast.

Comment: BTW. I have alread thought about using the interop RealFileEx method to store the data directly into the target array, but this does only work for files then and not for streams.